# Windows 7 - View list of sent files (Firewall)

Tags: windows-7, firewall, file-transfer

Is it possible to view any files that have been uploaded from the computer through the firewall? I have been using a keylogger and my AntiVirus flagged it as a virus today. I would like to know if its been sending a log over the internet as opposed to just keeping it locally like it should be.

Alternatively, if anyone else has experiences with the Family Keylogger (http://www.spyarsenal.com/familykeylogger/) could you shed some light on whether or not it is safe?

EDIT: I used wireshark and Procmon to monitor it for a bit but I can't see anything suspicious there. The application didnt use any TCP/UDP connections according to Procmon.

Comment: You could try using Wireshark to monitor the network traffic

Comment: "...  else has experiences with the Family Keylogger..." - that's a separate question. You should ask a new question and remove it from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been using a keylogger and my AntiVirus flagged it as a virus today. I would like to know if its been sending a log over the internet as opposed to just keeping it locally like it should be.

You can use `netstat` to see if your logger has a socket open. See [The netstat command can now display process IDs...](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980).

Related: the antivirus probably flagged it due to behavior (sniffing keystrokes). White list it if you approve it.

> Is it possible to view any files that have been uploaded from the computer through the firewall?

It depends on the firewall. But you need to know what host or server the key logger is communicating with. If you don't know, then its probably not going to be helpful to you.

Depending on the firewall, you may or may not have the logs. The firewall built into a Verizon or Comcast internet gateway is probably not going to have a lot of useful information due to a lack of history.

Other firewalls would likely do better. My m0n0wall is configurable, so I can perform remote logging for offline analysis if required:

[image]

A [web application firewall](http://www.google.com/#q=web+application+firewall) may help with your requirements. It will allow you to filter and monitor higher level protocols like HTTP.

If the key logger is egressing data, then it can defeat some analysis by encrypting the stream. SSL/TLS will do nicely and its readily available. The folks who break into US systems regularly egress 20 or 40 GB of data. And because they use SSL/TLS, the contractors don't even know what was taken (see, for example, Brennan's book on [America the Vulnerable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060571292)).

Answer (score 1):

A firewall set properly could block all programs that try to talk out to the web without having been told they can by you. (barring the fact that things can craftily take other routes there).
 I use the "Windows firewall notifier" program, which can set the windows own firewall into actually working, and uses windows own logging to alert. Then it becomes a pain to allow and block (train it). Because most of the programs have to be allowed before they can do any talking out, I know if any program tries. While that would not give a prior log, it would be better than having to see every I/O that occurs.

A good anti-virus or anti-Malware should be , and will spot mouse and key hooking programs, they should spot game trainers which change ram locations, and hacks that change normal dlls and exes and all. Keyloggers are one way that a virus might aquire your information.

Huristic (that means a sort of AI for baddies) should be finding these things and tagging them as evil, even if the purpose of them is for good. The user then knows if they installed it for a purpose, or if it arrived on the computer without thier knowlege.

If an item is in AV AMW  databases, which are mostly about specific programs or specific string of code, it could still observe any keylogger as something the user would want to know about. A totally legitimate keylogger could be used for evil purposes, so I would hope it would never be removed from tossing up a flag.

https://www.virustotal.com/ and uploading smaller executables (upload size limitation) can assist in guessing if something is a real virus or just a hack, because different AV vendors will know more or less about a specific baddie or legit program. It is not real practical to install many many Antiviruses on a computer, and totally bad to have that many activly scanning, so uploading it there could be usefull.

Hundreds of legitimate programs and hacks are marked by AV programs as being bad, because they have suspicious behaviours that a virus might apply. The humans (some human) still have to (attempt) to sort out what is really bad and what was not bad.

Unless the program has been tested by users, the AV masters, or the author , users or some genius somehow assures the Anti-virus company that is is Not a Virus, so they can specifically set it out as good , it will keep being tagged as bad.

You can also bet that unless all the code is releaced, and somehow all of it is gone through, things are going to be missed.
If they start missing keyloggers ,  well :-)